# HTML centered DIV

Tags: css, html, center, css-reset

I am trying to center a div. This is my code:

```
<!Doctype Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
            <div id="content" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>Beispiel: DIV Container horizontal zentrieren.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It isn't completely center, because I set in the CSS reset that text-align is left. If I remove this line everything is fine. Why is text-align: center; of the div with the id #content not overriding the CSS reset?

Comment: Is it simply your default rule matches the <p> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `!important` to overwrite that (leaving the p tag)

```
#content{margin:0 auto; background:red; width: 500px; text-align: center !important;}
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/pKePx/2/)**

Or else you can write css for p tag

```
#content p{text-align: center }
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/pKePx/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem :)

Comment: It is not recommended to overide styles with `!important` because you end up with a mess of cascading issues. http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsbin.com/irumef/1/)

Key point is

```
margin: 0 auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, less markup:

```
<!Doctype Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content{
                width: 500px;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            #content p {
                text-align:center; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Beispiel: DIV Container horizontal zentrieren.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In most cases it's better to prevent useing ìnline-styles`. Also move your styles in an seperate css file for a better maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML * tag means its consider all tags strictly the property as you mention in between,  you need to little change your style please visit link